# Remove first word from char array and print it out using pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

So i'm trying to make a small program where i have a string with word an i need to delete nth word from it and then print it out using pointers.

I made a part where i can delete nth word but i can't understand how to print it using pointers.

EDIT(Sorry i forgot to add the code):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void removeAll(char * str, char * toRemove);

int main(){
    char *words[100];
    char removeword[100];
    printf("Enter your sentence: ");
    gets(words);
    printf("Enter word to delete: ");
    gets(removeword);
    removeAll(words, removeword);
    printf("Word after deleting: %s", words);

}

void removeWord(char * str, char * toRemove)
{
    int i, j, stringLen, toRemoveLen;
    int found;

    stringLen   = strlen(str);
    toRemoveLen = strlen(toRemove);


    for(i=0; i <= stringLen - toRemoveLen; i++)
    {
        found = 1;
        for(j=0; j<toRemoveLen; j++)
        {
            if(str[i + j] != toRemove[j])
            {
                found = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(str[i + j] != ' ' && str[i + j] != '\t' && str[i + j] != '\n' && str[i + j] != '\0')
        {
            found = 0;
        }


        if(found == 1)
        {
            for(j=i; j<=stringLen - toRemoveLen; j++)
            {
                str[j] = str[j + toRemoveLen];
            }

            stringLen = stringLen - toRemoveLen;

            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:

```
char *pWord = words;
for (int i=0; pWord[i]; ++i) {
    const char *ch = pWord[i];
    while(*ch) {
        putchar(*ch++);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: If you can find the word, why can't you print it? Maybe copy it to another array before removing it from the string.

Comment: Show the code that tries to print it, we're not going to write it for you.

Comment: `gets(words);` - If that doesn't flag your compile with at-least warnings, if not outright errors, about type mismatching pointers, you seriously need to turn up your warning levels. You also need to forget you ever heard of the function `gets`. It has been removed from the standard library and should **never** be used.

Comment: Aside from `words` having the wrong type and `removeWord` being renamed to `removeAll`, it should work as expected.  What exactly are you having trouble printing?

Comment: I need to print the new array using pointer, i've tried but it gives me errors, the code that i've tried is on 2nd edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code there are some compile time errors. Which is, you have decleared and used `void removeAll(char * str, char * toRemove);` function instead of `void removeWord(char * str, char * toRemove)`.

Following is corrected working code. See it working [here](https://ideone.com/1eLmCg):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void removeWord(char * str, char * toRemove);

int main(){
    char words[100];
    char origional[100];
    char removeword[100];
    printf("Enter your sentence: ");
    gets(words);
    printf("Enter word to delete: ");
    gets(removeword);
    strcpy(origional, words);
    removeWord(words, removeword);
    printf("\nWord before deleting: %s", origional);
    printf("\nWord after deleting: %s", words);

}

void removeWord(char * str, char * toRemove)
{
    int i, j, stringLen, toRemoveLen;
    int found;

    stringLen   = strlen(str);
    toRemoveLen = strlen(toRemove);


    for(i=0; i <= stringLen - toRemoveLen; i++)
    {
        found = 1;
        for(j=0; j<toRemoveLen; j++)
        {
            if(str[i + j] != toRemove[j])
            {
                found = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(str[i + j] != ' ' && str[i + j] != '\t' && str[i + j] != '\n' && str[i + j] != '\0')
        {
            found = 0;
        }


        if(found == 1)
        {
            for(j=i; j<=stringLen - toRemoveLen; j++)
            {
                str[j] = str[j + toRemoveLen];
            }

            stringLen = stringLen - toRemoveLen;

            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Enter your sentence: Hello there how are you?
Enter word to delete: how
Word before deleting: Hello there how are you?
Word after deleting: Hello there  are you?
```

Comment: Yeah that was my fault with this, but i also need to print new array(without deleted word) by using pointers.

Comment: @KyryloSkobylko For this you need to copy _the initial input_. Answer is updated. If you need something else then mention expected output.

Comment: That's good but i thought that output will be something like array address in memory(E.g 0x000008b) and then convert it back to normal view. P.s sorry for my bad english

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. But if you wants to print the address then use `%p` format specifier. e.g. `printf("%p", removeword);`.

Comment: Here's the example but in c++ where i used string: [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/KBC9AKRh) . I just can't understand how to do it in C.

Comment: You are doing the same thing when you are passing parameters in `char * str` and `char * toRemove`. You can do the same using local variables instead of creating _parameters_.